# Copying Shape_Length and Shape_Area data (replace geometry tool) to other rows, or suitable alternatives using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am working on mapping extents for historical construction plans using ArcMap 10.6. I have sets of these blueprints that I must draw out dozens of similar polygons using the replace geometry tool, but on the larger and more complex polygons, I find myself making errors that slow my workflow down.

Is there is not a way for me to copy the polygon data, so that I only need to make one polygon that can be moved to other rows, what would be an alternative other than just continuing to draw out each sheet?

Comment: Are some of the polygons you are needing to create the same but you need to show them at different locations and later join them to existing attribute tables?

Comment: I apologize if my post is unclear, I can edit it! Anyways, to answer your question, this whole project is being done on a single attribute table. There are thousands of records that are referring to TIFs of sheets of historical parcel maps/road maps/e.t.c. Many of these sheets belong to the same set of plans, and thus have identical extents that I have to map for each sheet. This is being done so that each sheet has a spatial reference that can be easily accessed when reading historical plans.

Comment: The newer sheets being entered are in a PDF format, with all the sheets from a set entered into a single PDF, so I can just do one extent for all of the sheets in that plan.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide clarifications.

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/copying-and-pasting-features.htm

Comment: So are you trying to duplicate features, or to copy the shape (geometry) from one feature to other (already existing) features?

Comment: Start editing, copy-paste the existing polygon.